# Bind grid to form: condicional displayfield list

Tags: javascript, extjs, binding, extjs5

In the example of my fiddle is made the binding of a grid to a form displayfields.

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1is6

In car field values are displayed in a list.

What I meant was:

First, the symbol list (dot) were not displayed before selecting a row;

Second, if there is only one car (as in the case of BART) was also not displayed the symbol of the list; that is, the list symbol will only appear if there is more than one car.

It should be simple with a condition if () {}, but for some detail I'm not succeed.

Could anyone give me an idea to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
if(value && value.indexOf(',') > -1){
   ...
}else{
   return value
}
```

I edited my fiddle.

If anyone has a better solution to this case please post